# why i am getting different ceiling values for the same number

Tags: java, math, floor

I am computing some values and to do so I need to find the ceiling of a number. I know that I can use `Math.ceil()`. But the issue is, when I use `Math.ceil(,5)` it gives me `1`, and `Math.ceil(50/100)` gives me `0`.

Please let me know what is happening to get different ceilings for different values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`math.ceil(50/100)` is the same as `math.ceil(0)`, since `50/100` is `0` (since integer division is performed here, and the result is therefore an integer).

`math.ceil(50.0/100.0)` would give you 1, since `50.0/100.0` will be computed with floating point division and result in `0.5`.

Comment: Integer division strikes again.